# How can I protect my files in app's document directory from reading by external tools(iFunbox/iTools etc)

Tags: ios, iphone, security

I want to develop an photo protected app. When first launch, it forces user to input an password and every time back to the app, user must input the same password again. User takes photo in my app and I store the photo in app's document directory.

It works well but someone can access content in the app's document through external tools like iFunbox, they can export the photos. So my app is not safe enough. I have considered that I can use `ZipArchive` to compress photos with an password when save photos and uncompress photos when using want to see the photos, but compressing and uncompressing will cost much time and battery, I think it is not an good idea.

Can someone give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NSData` `writeToFile:options:error:` with the option `NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete` which will write it encrypted. This will only protect the files when the iOS device is locked.

Alternatively you can encrypt the file yourself with CommonCrypto AES and save the key in the keychain.

Comment: I am sorry `NSData writeToFile:options:error:` with `NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete` option does not work, I can also export the file out in my iMac and read the content in it.

Comment: You are on a jailbroken iPhone I guess. So CommonCrypto would seem to be the best direction. On the plus side AES has help from sone hardware instructions.

Comment: No, my iPhone isn't jailbroken. Some tools on mac can access the file system of iPhone. AES is my last choice because I think it will take much time to encrypt and decrypt a large photo.

Comment: I am aware of accessing files with apps I have a couple, but I am surprised that a file written with `NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete` was accessible unencrypted. I will be looking at that tomorrow.

Comment: I don't think write the file with `NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete ` will encrypt the file. You can have it a try, I do it like this.`NSString * test = @"Override point for customization after application launch." ;
    NSData * data = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
    NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] ;
    NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"] ;
    [data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete error:nil] ;`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot what that did: It is protection when the iPhone is locked. It is encrypted but when the iPhone unlocks the file is available decrypted. Probably the simplest way to go is with "RNCryptor" by Rob Napier. Keep the key in the keychain.

Comment: Thank you! I will consider "RNCryptor" if I didn't get a better solution.